# Git commands - Some commit details not showing when calling git log

Tags: git, github

I'm trying to understand why some commits have full details and others are missing the details in output...

`

```
$ git log --all --pretty="%cn - %cr - %h - %s" --author='user name 2' --since="2022-10-27" --until="2022-11-09" --shortstat

GitHub - 6 days ago - 5e9d2c71 - Merge pull request #233 from repo/fix/user_name2/item-348
GitHub - 10 days ago - 394779f5 - Merge pull request #238 from repo/feature/user_name2/item-347
GitHub - 13 days ago - 26e8f3a5 - Merge pull request #235 from repo/feature/user_name2/item-341
** 12 files changed, 328 insertions(+), 16 deletions(-)**
```

`this next user output is missing details ** 12 files changed, 328 insertions(+), 16 deletions(-)**`

```
$ git log --all --pretty="%cn - %cr - %h - %s" --author='user name' --since="2022-10-27" --until="2022-11-09" --shortstat

GitHub - 5 days ago - 8e9d2c71 - Merge pull request #183 from repo/fix/user_name/item-448
GitHub - 7 days ago - 194779f5 - Merge pull request #178 from repo/feature/user_name/item-447
GitHub - 10 days ago - 86e8f3a5 - Merge pull request #175 from repo/feature/user_name/item-441
```

`

What can be the reason for this missing detail in the output, even though the commits have details in GitHub web UI?

I'm trying to understand if this is a bug or user error of some soft? I can't find any posts online about missing details.

Comment: The second log lists only merges.

Answer (score 1):

You are pointing at merge commits.

By default, `git log` will not display diff information about merge commits (no diff when using `-p`, no file list with `--name-only` or `--name-status` ...).

You have to provide explicitly one of the merge options ([link to docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---diff-mergesoffnoneonfirst-parent1separatemcombinedcdense-combinedccremerger)) to change that : try adding `--cc` or `-m` to your command.